# How to fill gap between house foundation and house overhang

Tags: foundation, crack

I have an old house that has been settling since 1956.

The house has a basement, and the upper floor joists extends out over the foundation about a foot. On the outside, the transition from the foundation to the outside "overhang" has a ~1/2 inch gap". From the outside, one can see the insulation, and at some places the asphalt sheeting has cracked and is gone, leaving openings into the house. See photos below.

[image]

[image]

What would be the best way of sealing this crack? I tried foam, bit where the asphalt sheeting is gone, the foam just goes through. I was thinking nailing a 1x2 long piece of wood, and then caulk with some kind of rubbery sealant.

[image]

Comment: I added an "overview" picture to make it clearer

Comment: Your plan sounds good. If you don't like how it looks, then you might use nails or even thumb tacks to attach the backer rod to each joist so that you can stretch it somewhat tight. On top of that you could install a massive bead of caulk. A triangle with about a 7/8" leg on the overhang and a 1/2" leg on the vertical surface would do it. You would have to check specs to verify that large gaps like that are okay, but it's easy to find exterior caulks that can do it.